# Syncing Cloudkit private database with Core Data creates a duplicate saved record

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

EDIT: Edited with code that saves a record to Core Data and Cloudkit in case it helps with diagnosing the issue.

Hello all and Happy Holidays,

I am having a bit of trouble working with Core Data and Cloudkit. Upon launch of my app I run a Cloudkit fetch to get all saved records from the private database in order to sync those records across devices and save them to Core Data if needed. So upon completion of the fetch I tried to run a check so the app would only create a new record in Core Data if it was not already there to avoid duplicates when syncing.

Here is the code:

```
func fetchZoneChanges(database: CKDatabase, databaseTokenKey: String, zoneIDs: [CKRecordZoneID], completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

    // Look up the previous change token for each zone

    var optionsByRecordZoneID = [CKRecordZoneID: CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOptions]()

    for zoneID in zoneIDs {
        let options = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOptions()
        options.previousServerChangeToken = nil //TODO: Read change token from disk
        optionsByRecordZoneID[zoneID] = options
    }

    let operation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation(recordZoneIDs: zoneIDs, optionsByRecordZoneID: optionsByRecordZoneID)

    operation.recordChangedBlock = { (record) in

        print("Record changed:", record)

        // Write this record change to memory - core data

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if record.recordType == "Deck" {

                let ckRecordID = record.recordID.recordName

                let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Deck>(entityName: "Deck")

                fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ckRecordID = %@", ckRecordID)

                let fetchRequestResults = try? self.managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

                if let existingDeck = fetchRequestResults?.first {

                    // We already have the deck in Core Data, just need to update it!

                    existingDeck.cKRecordToDeck(record)

                } else {

                    // We don't have the deck in Core Data, so make a new one!

                    let deckEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Deck", in: self.managedContext)

                    let deckName =  Deck(entity: deckEntity!, insertInto: self.managedContext)

                    deckName.isCreatedByMe = true

                    deckName.cKRecordToDeck(record)
                }


            } else {
```

Trying to debug I set a breakpoint in the else block for creating a new Core Data "Deck" entity and noticed that it fires off when the fetch returns the record from Cloudkit that I had just created on the device and saved to Core Data. Yet the app thinks it is not in Core Data and creates a new duplicate record.

Saving record code:

```
func saveItem(_ name: String) {


    guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Deck", in: managedContext) else{
        print("Could not save item")
        return
    }

    let deckName =  Deck(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

    deckName.name = name

    deckName.isCreatedByMe = true

    do {
        try managedContext.save()

    }

    catch {
        let saveError = error as NSError
        print(saveError)
    }

    let zoneID = CKManager.defaultManager.sharedZone?.zoneID

    let deckSetToBeSaved = deckName.deckToCKRecord(zoneID)

    privateDatabase.save(deckSetToBeSaved) { (record, error) in
        print("New record saved")
        print(error as Any)
    }



}
```

Here is the outlined sequence for better clarity of the issue:

1. Create a new "Deck" record within the app which is successfully saved to **both** Core Data and my Cloudkit private database.
2. Re-open the app to trigger the Cloudkit fetch on the private database.
3. Fetch runs and displays successfully with the only duplicate being the record just created and saved on the device.

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Do you have 'recordName' in the index list?

Comment: Hello, El Tomato. Thank for your reply. If i am understanding correctly i do believe i do. If you need to me edit with other code i can do so.

Comment: Your code doesn't show the call to `saveItem`. Where does that happen? If there's something preventing that from happening, you'd see the duplication behavior you're describing.